# Dynamically Applying 0 or more ng-repeat filters in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have the following view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" >
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.pageViews}}</td>
    <td>{{user.urls}}</td>
</tr>
```

I can statically apply multiple filters like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:idFilter | filter:pageViewFilter | filter:urlsFilter">
```

How can I dynamically apply anywhere from 0 to N filters to my ng-repeat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access filters in your controller by $filter. Here is the **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EGVwG/6/

```
<ul ng-repeat="num in getData()" >
  <li>{{num.val}}</li>
</ul>

$scope.getData = function() {
  var finalData = $scope.arrVal;

  if($scope.bFilterEnabled)
    finalData = $filter('filter')(finalData, $scope.searchText);

  if($scope.bSortEnabled)
    finalData = $filter('orderBy')(finalData, 'val');

  return finalData;
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm with you, but how about a custom filter? Would it be `$filer('myCustomFilter')` ?

Comment: @Alan Yes.$filer('myCustomFilter') will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

How about applying all the filters but some of them 'do nothing' (pass-all condition).
Or, you could create another custom filter to chain the result.

Comment: I'm a angularJS noob, so I'm not really sure how to create a custom filter to chain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11722324/1238847 shows you the example, how to combine filters.  You should be able to create an filter which does the same.

Comment: See also [Creating Angular Filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters).  You could pass a $scope object property as a parameter to your custom filter.  That object can indicate which filters to apply.  E.g., `<tr ng=repeat="user in users | myMultiFilter:filtersToApply">`.  $scope property filtersToApply would indicate which filters to apply.

Comment: I like the "apply all but some do nothing" approach.  An example of that can be found on the [filter page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter).