# AngularJS - Transclude and access ng-repeat filtered list in a sub-directive,

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to tile elements that get in to `ng-repeat` (set up their `css` based on the filtered list)

Ideally I would like to use html markup like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="row in rows">
     <h6>{{row.name}}</h6>
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items|filter:row" tile>{{ item.name }}</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Is it possible for me to access the list that is being passed to `ng-repeat`? (any other way than [AngularJS - how to get an ngRepeat filtered result reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721863/angularjs-how-to-get-an-ngrepeat-filtered-result-reference))
2. Can I somehow `transclude` the items, so the `tile` directive would actually apply css (I want to abstract `ng-style="{top:getTop(item),left:getLeft(item)}"` etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to access the list that is being passed to ng-repeat? (any other way than AngularJS - how to get an ngRepeat filtered result reference)

I think you'll need to do what you saw in the link you referenced:

```
ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items|filter:row))" tile>
```

Assuming your `tile` directive does not create a new scope, it will share the scope that ng-repeat creates (one scope per item).  So the `filteredItems` property will be available to your directive.

> Can I somehow transclude the items, so the tile directive would actually apply CSS (I want to abstract ng-style="{top:getTop(item),left:getLeft(item)}" etc.)

Your `tile` directive has access to the `li` element on which it is defined.  So you can simply call, e.g., `element.addClass(...)`.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the filtered list to an isolated scope ? like: `<ul tile="items|filter:row"><li ng-repeat="item in items" tiled>...</li></ul>` ? 
(move the filtering to the parent element) ?

Comment: You will run into trouble trying to use an isolated scope with ng-repeat.  See section "Combining ng-repeat with other directives" on the [FAQ page](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq).