# Pass ng-repeat expression to ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The html template contains a list of items filtered

```
        <ul class="gift_info">
         <li ng-repeat="code in codes | filter:{id_id:detail.id}">{{code.discount}}</li>
        </ul>
```

Below this list there is a button with code like

```
<button type="button" ng-click="add_something(repeat_expression_needed)">Add more</button>
```

The goal is to feed the items from ng-repeat above to function below as a param (collection, array, whatever).
Is it doable via mere template directives or some controller tricks need to be involved?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Use the button to add an item to the list that could appear in the ng-repeat list or have a button on every ng-repeat item to act upon the object in that list?  if the former, you just add to the model item "codes" and it will automatically appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code using the method @Jonathan pointed out

```
<ul class="gift_info">
    <li ng-repeat="code in (filteredCodes = (codes | filter: {id_id:detail.id})">{{code.discount}}</li>
</ul>
```

and then

```
<button type="button" ng-click="add_something(filteredCodes)">Add more</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression inside of the ng-repeat to assign a variable that will hold the collection and will then be available inside the scope.

See answer:
[How can I obtain the result array of an angular "| filter" expression in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050533/how-can-i-obtain-the-result-array-of-an-angular-filter-expression-in-a-varia)