# How to ngShow a div when filtered search bar returns nothing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

first I'll provide background info then show some code snippets.

1. I have an ng-repeat that is repeating box-like widgets with data/information inside.
2. I have a search bar that filters the data in the widgets and only shows widgets that contain the string in the search bar.
3. With number 2 in mind, when a string is entered that is not in any of the widgets, it leaves the page blank with no widgets. (it makes widgets without that string disappear)

What I want: is to show a div when no result is returned instead of having a blank page.

For the sake of examples, I have:

```
<input type = "text" data-ng-model = "searchWidgets" />

<div id="main-content-body" data-ng-repeat="widget in widgets | filter:searchWidgets">

    <div id="falsy-search" ng-show="!searchWidgets.length">
        <h1 id="inset-message" class="text-center">No Results Found</h1>
    </div>

    <section>
        (this is where all the widgets get displayed)
    </section>

</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your time and input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a few options, one of the easiest is to save the filteredWidgets as its own object, and just use ng-show:

```
<div id="main-content-body" data-ng-repeat="widget in (filteredWidgets = (widgets | filter:searchWidgets))">

    <div id="falsy-search" ng-show="!searchWidgets.length || filteredWidgets.length == 0">
        <h1 id="inset-message" class="text-center">No Results Found</h1>
    </div>

    <section>
        (this is where all the widgets get displayed)
    </section>

</div>
```

[Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050533/how-can-i-obtain-the-result-array-of-an-angular-filter-expression-in-a-varia)

Comment: I changed the ng-show a little. I have `<div ng-show="!searchWidgets.length == 0|| filteredWidgets.length == 0">`. Now it shows the div whenever i search anything or search incorrectly.

Comment: @Kepler my first guess would be "!searchWidgets.length == 0". I believe the ! is extra (and the cause of this issue)

Comment: Correct again, you genius! However, when I backspace the string the search bar now, the div stays. Thanks for letting me bug you with this :)

Comment: That probably because searchWidgets.length is 0 then. I guess, my next question would be, "Why do you have that as part of the ng-show?". In my mind, this div should only depend on the results.

Comment: If it is not there, the div appears whenever there is something in the searchbar.