# Angular get row count with several filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am having a problem with `row` count in after `ng-repeat` and more then one `filter`, I want to count the current number of rows after filtering the table with more then one filter, example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter}">
</tr>
```

The `m_resource, m_id` are filds in `data`, I can't use [as filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data) due `badidnet` error, is there amother way to do it?

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. Can you clarify?

Comment: I want to count the numer of rows, after applying 3 filters.

Comment: is there a reference for $last?

Comment: Question already asked. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data)

Comment: @RomainDeSaJardim I wrote this in the question, not possible for more then one filter.

Comment: @RomainDeSaJardim - wrote a link to this answer - as filter

Comment: try this `row =( data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter}).length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that works even if you add limitTo filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in filtered = (data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter}) | limitTo: 5">
```

Then you have just to do

```
{{filtered.length}}
```

[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Nk8qy/963/)

Comment: Trying and posting the result.

Comment: Perfact!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
ng-repeat="person in filtered = ( data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter} )"
```

And then use `{{ filtered.length }}` for the number of rows.

Comment: trying and posting the result.

Comment: Makes sense, because limitTo slices part of the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in rows = (data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter})">
    </tr>
</table>
<span>There are {{ rows.length }} rows in the table</span>
```

Same question : [How can I obtain the result array of an angular "| filter" expression in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050533/how-can-i-obtain-the-result-array-of-an-angular-filter-expression-in-a-varia)