# AngularJS : How to reference filtered ng-repeat items from a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have some JSON data that is rendered out via the ng-repeat directive, and the results are then filtered via some checkboxes/drop-downs, and some custom filter functions in my controller.

I now want to add a function to my controller that is triggered by an 'ng-change' on some of the checkboxes, that can reference the current list of items in my 'ng-repeat'. I realise I can reference these values from a custom filter, for example `$scope.filterProvider = function(item)`, but this function is then called for each and every item in the ng-repeat, which isn't what I want - I want the function to just be called each time a checkbox is checked/unchecked, and I need that function to be able to reference the items in my ng-repeat...does that make sense to anyone?! And if so, does anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Bit of a head scratcher that one, but apparently you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721863/angularjs-how-to-get-an-ngrepeat-filtered-result-reference

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what I'm trying to do - that works a treat :-)

Answer (score 2):

Say you have `ng-repeat="item in items"`, then you may use something like `ng-click=thisAmazingFct(item)` that will pass the current item while calling thisAmazingFct.

If you prefer using the index of the item in the items array, use something like `ng-click=thisAmazingFctByIndex($index)` where `$index` is automatically set to the current item index by angular with the `ng-repeat` directive.