# ng-repeat to render empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to render an array of possible authors as inputs so that which authors are assigned can be edited.

```
.form-multiple-item(ng-repeat="author in story.authors")
  input(type='text', ng-model="author")
```

Problem is if I want to add an additional blank input after the existing inputs. How can I do that?

```
.form-multiple-item(ng-repeat="author in story.authors")
  input(type='text', ng-model="author")
input(type='text', ng-model="author")
```

For example this wouldn't work as author wouldn't be on the correct scope.

If I have `story.authors = [""]` I want to render an blank input for the user to fill out. But that wouldn't work either as `""` just gets ignored by ng-repeat instead of rendering an empty input to be filled. How do I do I either render an empty input or perhaps get another ng-model somewhere inserted into an array in another scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Angular way of doing this to "put a dot in your model". Your `authors` model should be an object instead of a string: `{ name: '' }` With the aforementioned object, you should be able to represent an empty input in your `ng-repeat`.

The `ng-model` in the `<input>` would look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="author.name" />
```

Comment: So basically it's necessary to complicate the structure this way?

Comment: Well, this should solve the problem b/c the object is not falsy like the empty string is. I think there are some valid reasons, I searched earlier when posting this, but all I found was this [very threatening sounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems) question. Though I know I've read it elsewhere. When I refactored some code to do just this, the code seemed more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

@Harry You asked why complicate things?

The reason is so that assignments work. The input controller will assign its value to whatever's in "ng-modal". If it's a normal variable, then the link to the original list will be lost. If it's an attribute of an object, then the link is preserved. Consider the two scenarios:

```
for author in authors:
   author = "joe"
```

See how authors doesn't get changed?

```
for author in authors:
   author.name = "joe"
```

Now the connection is preserved.

Does that make sense?