# Ng-model undefined in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having some "problems" reading an ng-model from the controller.

I want to do this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="code">
<button ng-click="setCode()">Login</button>
```

And in my controller access that variable like this:

```
 $scope.setCode = function(){
    alert($scope.code);
  }
```

That is what I want to do but my code variable is undefined.

I found 2 ways to get this to work:

1) Passing the variable as an argument

```
<input type="text" ng-model="code">
<button ng-click="setCode(code)">Login</button>
```

and:

```
$scope.setCode = function(code){
    alert(code);
  }
```

2) Declaring my variable as an object

```
<input type="text" ng-model="code.text">
<button ng-click="setCode()">Login</button>
```

and:

```
$scope.code = {text: 'foo'};

[...]

$scope.setCode = function(){
    console.log($scope.code);
  }
```

(I prefer the second one)

But I am a little confused about what I should do. It's ok to declare my ng-models like objects? I have to declare ALL my models like objects?

---

EDIT: [Here is a Plnkr of the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/X8CpI0DlHTgSgxHeuptw?p=preview)

In this example (I am using the [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) framework), I declare a variable code with the value test, when I change the model in the input and press the Start button, in theory I have to see in an alert the new value of the model. But what I see is the old one.

Thanks!

Comment: The first example should work fine.

Comment: Make sure that controller scope and the scope on which the ng-model is being set are same, directives like ng-if and ng-repeat create their own scope. Otherwise your first example should be working fine.

Comment: @DesigningtheCode oh thx for pointing out on ng-if, i was hiding email field this way and was wondering what the heck...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed your plnkr example using object model instead of primitive type.

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.code = "test";

$scope.setCode = function(){
    alert($scope.model.code);
}
```

See the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/n586TbeWatJdbSYiBi4P?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar problem as OP and your method solved it. Do you have any idea why OP's code didn't work in the plnkr he shared as a comment in Erik's answer?

Comment: @TadDonaghe You can check the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems). I'm not familiar with ionic-framework, but i think the `label` and `button` tag will introduce new scope here so that we can only use a non-primitive object to pass reference.

Answer (score 7):

Your first example is working, [here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GAI4zeCWr9hhSoiK6ldE?p=preview).

If you hit the button without entering any text into the input field you get an alert `undefined`. `$scope.code` gets defined the moment you enter something to its bound field `ng-model="code"`.

You could initialize it to a default in your controller too:

```
$scope.code = 'my default value';
```

Comment: I already tried it, but is the same. Here is a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/X8CpI0DlHTgSgxHeuptw?p=preview) of what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ionic's directive will create the new scope, if you want to use the *code* object in controller directly, you must set ng-controller to ion-content in your HTML page, not to the router state.