# Why is $scope not getting passed to controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason `$scope.username` is not being passed to my controller. On click `registerUser()` `$scope.username` is undefined. I do have a scope and the function is running just no $scope.username.

For example:

**HTML:**

```
 <input bs-form-control
     type="text"
     ng-model="username"
     label="Username"
     />

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="registerUser()">Register</button>
```

controller:

```
    .controller("loginController", ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.registerUser = function(){
                console.log($scope.username) // <=== undefined!
            }

  }])
```

My controller is passed using state:

```
.state('register', {
            url: "/register",
            templateUrl: "/static/html/profile/register.html",
            controller: "loginController"
        })
```

Comment: add the code where u included ng-controller in html...

Comment: Can you create a plunker with your code? Are you sure `bs-form-control` doesn't create a new isolated scope?

Comment: the code is fine. Are you sure you've added ng-app ? http://plnkr.co/edit/Elwzp9aWyPPyxKR25MME?p=preview

Comment: @Srinath you don't need ng-controller if you specify controller in your router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `bs-form-control` creates a new isolated scope. What you should do is either use objects on your scope ([Does my ng-model really need to have a dot to avoid child $scope problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems))
or use the new "constroller as" syntax introducted in AngularJS 1.2. It works with ui-router too!

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hkmMGbTtURSHDH84miiK?p=preview

#### Routing:

```
.state('register', {
    url: "/register",
    templateUrl: "/static/html/profile/register.html",
    controller: "loginController as loginCtrl"
})
```

#### Template:

```
<input bs-form-control type="text" ng-model="loginCtrl.username" label="Username" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="loginCtrl.registerUser()">Register</button>
```

#### Controller:

Use `this` instead of `$scope`:

```
.controller("loginController", [
    function () {
        this.registerUser = function(){
            console.log(this.username);
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Yes when I strip things out it works. bs-panel seems to messy things up, removed it. I will also looked at the DOT issues too