# AngularJS : directive in ng-repeat. Scope twoway binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have directive with isolated scope and two-way data binding.

```
    app.directive('inputField', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^ngModel',
            scope: {
                data: '=ngModel',
            },
            template: "<input type='text' ng-model='data' />",
        };
    });
```

If I put this directive to page. All works fine. Data in page scope and directive scope is equal.
But if I put directive in ng-repeat, directive not populate data to page scope.
How to resolve this problem?

Here's [example of code](http://plnkr.co/edit/yEWALFCNM3mPajPyQuNg?p=preview).

Comment: why ng-model on parent element?? `require: '^ngModel',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p3kIGw0x92NIVqgkZjJd?p=preview).

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data2">
    <input-field ng-model="data2[$index]"></input-field>     <br>
</div>
```

the issue was there because you are using ng-model without dot.

checked it using console.log. read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems).

Comment: This (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) article explain bug reasons to me. Thanks for link and help.