# Binding stops working in input within ng-if

Tags: angularjs

For some reason binding doesn't work on an input within `ng-if` block in a directive

so this, doesn't work:

```
app.directive 'foo', ->
    restrict: 'E'
    scope:
       type:'='
    template: "<input ng-if=\"type === 'string'\" ng-model='filterText'>
                  <div> {{filterText}} </div>"


<foo type="'string'" />
```

it works fine outside of directive or without `ng-if`. Wrapping input inside of a div with `ng-if` not helping. Is it a bug?

[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/penuhilahujo/8/edit)

Comment: What isn't working?  Your jsbin link seems fine to me.  If I change type to 'test' the input hides.  Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: no, you see it's not displaying {{filterText}} as it should. And if you remove ng-if it works fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused by the ng-if introducing a new scope combined with the fact that you ng-model "has not dot in it".

This works:

```
template: "<div ng-init='holder={}'> <input ng-if=\"type === 'string'\" ng-model='holder.filterText'></div>
               <div> {{holder.filterText}}</div>"
```

See the directive info at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf and notice the text "This directive creates new scope."
For the "dot-in-model", see for example
[Does my ng-model really need to have a dot to avoid child $scope problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems)
or
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot
Basically when reading the value it will be read correctly traversing scope prototypes, but when modifying the value it will be written to the very own scope.

Comment: I have a link to jsbin, feel free to play with that. Apparently it's not scoping problem, this seems to be something different

Comment: Sorry, did not notice the small blue link. I don't understand why you say "Apparently it's not scoping problem". See my edited answer where I illustrated my point with code.

Comment: Oh... interesting... this http://jsbin.com/penuhilahujo/9/edit worked. So you're right

Answer (score 1):

Since `ng-if` creates a new scope, you just need to do this

```
ng-model='$parent.filterText'
```

Also, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18343089/304319).

Answer (score -3):

The `<div>` tag isn't closed in your example, nor is the `ng-if` applied to that node.

Try this:

```
template: "<input  ng-model='filterText'>
                  <div ng-if=\"type === 'string'\"> {{filterText}}"</div>"
```

Comment: Oh... gosh... I've fixed it, I closed it, I modified jsbin. It still doesn't work

Comment: You're missing the point... I need ng-if applied to input. I want to have/not have input field depending on `type`