# AngularJS : directive not working when inside another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, transclusion

i can't make the input updates the model when it is inside the list-select-option directive.

but, when i use the directive cefenRadio directly on the view it's capable of update the model, as i want

probably the problem is on the transfer of the model between the two dirctives, but i can't discover the right way to do this.

anyone have some idea? thx

directives.js

```
;
(function (angular, undefined) {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.directives')
    .directive('listSelect', listSelect)
    .directive('listSelectOptions', listSelectOptions)
    .directive('cefenRadio', cefenRadio)
    .controller('listSelectController', listSelectController);

    var template = [
        '<div class="lista-item">',
            '<div class="tile-left"></div>',
            '<div class="tile-content">',
                '<h3 class="lista-item-title">{{title}}</h3>',
                '<h4 class="lista-item-subtitle" ng-if="subtitle">{{subtitle}}</h4>',
                '<ng-transclude></ng-tranclude>',
            '</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('');

    function listSelect() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: template,
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            priority: 2,
            scope: {
                array: '=ngModel',
                title: '@',
                subtitle: '@'
            },
            link: linker,
            controller: listSelectController
        };
    }

    function linker(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('listSelect', scope);

    }

    listSelectController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function listSelectController($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.initiateOptions = function() {
            console.log('initiating listSelectorOptions');

            return {
                array: $scope.array,
                title: $scope.title
            };
        };
    }


    var templateOption = [
        '<div class="lista-item-selecoes">',
            '<p class="lista-item-selecionado">Opção selecionada</p>',
            '<div class="lista-options">',
                '<div class="lista-options-group" ng-repeat="instance in array">',
                    '<cefen-radio type="{{type}}" title="{{title}}" index="{{$index}}" name="{{name}}" model="model" ng-value="instance" prop="{{property}}"></cefen-radio>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('');

    function listSelectOptions() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: templateOption,
            replace: true,
            require: '^listSelect',
            scope: {
                type: '@',
                name: '@',
                property: '@value',
                model: '='
            },
            link: linkerOption
        };
    }

    function linkerOption(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
        console.log('listSelectOptions', scope.instance, scope.model);

        attrs.$observe('model', updateValue);
        angular.extend(scope, parentCtrl.initiateOptions());
    }

    var templateRadio = [
        '<input type="{{type || \'radio\'}}" id="{{title}}_{{index}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="ngModel" ng-true-value="{{ngValue}}">',
        '<label for="{{title}}_{{index}}">',
            '<span></span>',
            '<span class="check"></span>',
            '<span class="box"></span>',
            '{{ngValue[property]}}',
        '</label>'
    ].join('');

    function cefenRadio() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: templateRadio,
            scope: {
                type: '@',
                title: '@',
                name: '@',
                index: '@',
                property: '@prop',
                ngModel: '=model',
                ngValue: '='
            },
            link: cefenRadiolinker
        };
    }

    function cefenRadiolinker(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('cefenRadio', scope.model);

        attrs.$observe('model', updateValue);
    }

    function updateValue(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            return newVal;
        }
    }
}(window.angular));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]>    <html class="no-js iem7" lang="pt-br"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="pt-br"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <base href="/ng/" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Fatores App</title>

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

        <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#26a69a">

        <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

        <!-- For iOS web apps. Delete if not needed. https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/issues/94 -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Fatores App">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">

        <!-- This script prevents links from opening in Mobile Safari. https://gist.github.com/1042026 -->
        <!--
        <script>(function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone")</script>
        -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="libs/toaster/toaster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="scripts/directives/spinner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/lista.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <link href="css/fx-input.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>


        <div id='content' ng-controller="mainController as main">

            <p class="well">{{main.selected.empresa}}</p>

            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="2" ng-model="main.selected.empresa">2</label>

            <cefen-radio type="checkbox" title="teste" index="0" name="teste" model="main.selected.empresa" ng-value="{Id:1, Name:'Qualquer'}" prop="Name"></cefen-radio>

            <list-select title="empresas" 
                          subtitle="informação" 
                          ng-model="main.empresas">
                <list-select-options type="radio" 
                                      name="empresas" 
                                      value="RazaoSocial"
                                      model="main.selected.empresa">
                </list-select-options>
            </list-select>


    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

    <!-- angular core -->
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/angular-loader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/angular-messages.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.3.6/i18n/angular-locale_pt-br.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--libraries-->
    <script src="libs/CryptoJS v3.1.2/crypto.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/ui-router-master/release/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-local-storage-master/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/HammerJS/hammer.2.0.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-q-spread-master/dist/q-spread.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/CodeSeven-toastr-4395be3/toastr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--config-->
    <script src="scripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--core-->
    <script src="scripts/core/core.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/core/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/core/constants.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/core/routes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/core/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/core/dataservice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--exception-->
    <script src="scripts/blocks/exception/exception.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/blocks/exception/exception.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/blocks/exception/exception-handler.provider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--logger-->
    <script src="scripts/blocks/logger/logger.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/blocks/logger/logger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--encrypt-->
    <script src="scripts/encrypt/encrypt.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/encrypt/cryptojs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/encrypt/encryptservice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--filters-->
    <script src="scripts/filters/filters.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/filters/hashById.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--storage-->
    <script src="scripts/storage/storage.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/storage/storage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--directives-->
    <script src="scripts/directives/directives.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/pageTitle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/formReset.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/seletor/materialCheckbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/seletor/listSelect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--layout-->
    <script src="scripts/layout/layout.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/layout/toolbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/layout/configuracao.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--auth-->
    <script src="scripts/auth/auth.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/auth/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/auth/authservice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--models-->
    <script src="scripts/models/models.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/user.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/dataSession.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/entidades.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--debug-->
    <script src="libs/debug/findMissingDirectives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/debug/findUndefinedExpressions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/debug/stopAngularOverrides.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('mainController', mainController);

    function mainController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.selected = {
            empresa: {id:1}
        };
        vm.empresas = [{
            "Id": 1,
            "RazaoSocial": "Odebrecht",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:19.313"
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            "RazaoSocial": "Associa",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:19.577"
        }, {
            "Id": 3,
            "RazaoSocial": "Fabrimonte",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:19.703"
        }, {
            "Id": 4,
            "RazaoSocial": "Codemi",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:19.857"
        }, {
            "Id": 5,
            "RazaoSocial": "Comeci",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:19.967"
        }, {
            "Id": 6,
            "RazaoSocial": "Decisão",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:20.047"
        }, {
            "Id": 7,
            "RazaoSocial": "TCB",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:20.123"
        }, {
            "Id": 8,
            "RazaoSocial": "Jetcon",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:20.217"
        }, {
            "Id": 9,
            "RazaoSocial": "Gesso Cariri",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:20.313"
        }, {
            "Id": 10,
            "RazaoSocial": "ACA",
            "Tarefas": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "Obras": [],
            "DataAtualizacao": "2014-12-26T20:28:20.39"
        }];
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are hitting the nested scope prototype issue. Change `model="model"` to contain a dot. I think the ng-repeat's scope is the issue. This problem is a real "gotcha" with angular. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17178943/266795

Comment: it's exactly this! thank you!