# shared state between controllers - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

About shared state between controllers. I have a hard time finding the *right* way to do this from all the possible solutions recommended on SO. I made this sketch to illustrate the basic idea I had about this so far using a factory.

There is the factory `myFactory`, that holds a shared variable `sharedVar`.

The controllers `Ctrl1, Ctrl2, Ctrl3` want to access always the updated version. They also can call an `updateViaHttp`.

[image: factory-controller-communication]

1. Is that the right **purpose of a factory**? (in general to share state,
   specific to the other options like service and provider)
2. If so, how to **watch changes** of the `sharedVar` in a proper way? (by
       reference of objects, $watch, events (broadcast, on), ...)
3. Is there a **general pattern** that works well **for objects, arrays and
   primitives**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You've got the basic idea right, assuming by 'factory' you mean 'service' -- it's kind of confusing, I know, because services are declared using factory functions. That said, it's an important distinction to make so that you'll have an easier time finding documentation, etc.
2. Watch changes either just by using object references and being careful about [watch depths in Angular](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html) (my preferred method) or by explicitly registering $watch statements (still be careful about watch depths). Generally I'm of the opinion that you shouldn't overuse broadcasts as it can make your code a little messy. It also kind of defeats the point of the service in this case, which is to be the source of shared state.
3. My general pattern for creating services is to bind everything I want to use to an object (both data and functions) and then return that object in the factory function. Sometimes you have to introduce some extra nesting so that the Javascript prototypical inheritance doesn't mess with you (see the watch depths thing again) but that's the general idea.

An example service for your set up:

```
angular.factory('shareAndUpdate', ['dependencyInjection', function(dependency) {
    var srvc = {};
    srvc.sharedVar = 'something';
    srvc.updateViaHttp = function(){ something };
    return srvc;
}]);
```

Comment: the example you gave seems to work as long as the updateViaHttp doesnt return an object. if so, and I assign srvc.sharedVar = returnedObj it breads the reference. is that true?

Comment: You can totally have nested objects inside of services, the only trick to it is that you have to be careful with how you're watching that value. The link I had there about watch depths talks about it more, but basically you can have issues when you change the properties but not the object, as then the object won't mark itself as "changed". Similarly, you have to be careful with how you watch a service's properties, see: http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/  Services are just singleton objects used by your whole app

Comment: can't get it to work, it I change the view the state of the factory is lost. its not persistent

Comment: Where are you declaring the service? How are you injecting it into your views? There's a lot that could be going on here, so it might be worthwhile for you to run through the official Angular service documentation to make sure you're checking all the boxes: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like a pubsub service:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-pubsub

However, in my experience, through proper design, you can minimize the necessity to share data in between non-nested controllers.

Sometimes it is unavoidable, though, for stuff like login credentials, permissions, stuff that is all-app-encompassing. In such occasions you can use a service to indeed share/get the state in between controllers, or you can go for the fully-fledged pubsub mechanism.

1. A factory is just another way of specifying a service. A factory, when called, gives an instance of a service. This service you can use for everything that you want, one of those things being sharing state in between your controllers.
2. You can watch a shared variable in many ways, the easiest being inheriting scopes, but, as you mentioned, sometimes your controllers don't necessarily inherit their scopes. Then you can use a pubsub service or just broadcast events on a shared scope for both controllers (like $rootScope, which is the parent of all controllers' scopes for your app).
3. If you were to use an existing pubsubservice, it would still be up to your implementing controllers to actually do the subscribe and watching on a specific variable and updating their corresponding scopes accordingly. However, that can be avoided if you design your app in such a way that your controllers inherit the variable from a shared scope. Then they will automatically update their stuff using the normal angular mechanism. That, sadly, can not always be achieved and then what you are left with is having to implement a pubsub service.

Answer (score 1):

factories vs services vs providers - only differences are related to how the Dependency Injector provides instances of them to you. Services are specifically designed for providing singletons, but are just a wrapper over factories that add the singleton specific functionality. Nothing stopping you from returning a singleton from a factory.

using services to share state - you need a singleton and a service makes defining and injecting singletons easy.

```
SomeService:
    var foo = {
        bar = 'a'; 
    };
    function getFoo() {
        return foo; 
    }

SomeController[SomeService injected here] :
    $scope.foo = SomeService.getFoo();
    $scope.$watch('foo.bar', ...);
    $scope.setFooBar = function(val) {
        $scope.foo.bar = val;
    };

<a href="" ng-click="setFooBar('2')">2</a>
```

The general pattern here is to never do a
`$scope.foo = { bar: 'Some other reference' };` because then all your other things depending on SomeService will *not* get the new reference when you overwrite it - the "infamous" [always use a "dot" in $scope stuff issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems).