# angular-datepicker: get ng-model value into scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs and I want to show the selected date and time of my datepicker in a `<pre>` tag by the scope of the `ng-model="abc"`.

[angular-datepicker (github)](https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/), [angular-datepicker (demo)](https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/app/index.html)

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div ng-controller="foo">
          <input type="datetime" class="form-control" date-time ng-model="myDate" format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM" placeholder="Select datetime">
          <pre>myDate: {{myDate}}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('demo', ['datePicker']).controller('foo', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //empty
}]);
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ntPLbrBBVQ6Gg7o4D2G?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the updated plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/Qagb78UDqXQrabcZucr6.

To get it working, I had to make `ng-model` point to an object.property  (`myDate.value`) in the `input`. And you can get the model value in the template like this:

```
<pre>
      myDate: {{myDate.value | date: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM"}}
</pre>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.myDate = {
        value: ''
};
```

Hope this answers your question. Here's the reason why `ng-model` need to have a dot - [Does my ng-model really need to have a dot to avoid child $scope problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems).

Comment: Now the problem is, that once a date is selected, the scope value does not update, when I select another date. How to achieve that?

Comment: That's weird. It was updating yesterday. Let me take a look.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. If you update it by typing, it doesn't update the date.

Comment: Hmm, can't make it work. What needs to be done to show the updated time with seconds too, without any formatting?

Comment: If you remove the formatting (`| date: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM"`), the result would give the minutes as well in UTC like this `2016-02-17T17:40:00.000Z`.

Comment: Ah thanks. Updated plnkr can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AqHyru2MVpdQn8oKe97S?p=preview). 

Additional Question: Is it possible to add ng-change="barFunc()" to the input and work with the scope values in this function?

Comment: Ah yes, remove the ` format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM"` in `input`, this would pick up the changes in minutes. Then change the result like this `myDate: {{myDate.value | date: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"}}`. This would make the `myDate` pick up changes in minutes. Update fiddle - http://plnkr.co/edit/Qagb78UDqXQrabcZucr6/. Hope this helps. Let me know if not :).

Comment: I tried ng-change, but that doesn't seem up pick the the changes you make to the input typing. Let me try with ng-watch.

Comment: Would be great if you can make it work with one of these.