# What should we use for assigning model data in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I would like to know the better way of assigning model name for each form elements using Angular JS.

I can assign it using individual scope variables.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/>
```

I can also assign it using singleton object.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="contact.firstName"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="contact.lastName"/>
```

Which is the better way of handling form data in terms of memory and execution time?

Answer (score 3):

You should choose the second option, in order to avoid issue with scope inheritance, see [the doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope.

Comment: It's generally always better to use the second format and not reference scope directly. It will help you move to Angular 2 eventually and not pollute the scope. The general rule is that if there's not a dot in it, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to Miško Hevery, the creator of AngularJS:

> Whenever you have ng-model there’s gotta be a dot in there somewhere.
>   If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong.

*The question is why?*

Because `ng-switch`, `ng-repeat`, etc. creates their own scopes.
For example, [have a look at this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0I4Xdec2RKeanv8pnYV3?p=preview)

```
      <form ng-submit='addName()'>

          Name 1: <input type='text' ng-model='name'/>
          <input type='submit' value="Submit"/>
      </form>

      <p ng-switch='true'>
          Name 2: <input type='text' ng-switch-when="true"  ng-model='name'/>
      </p>
      <p>
          Name 3: <input type='text' ng-model='name'/>
      </p>
```

**Output:**

[image]

When you type in the `Name 1` text box, the value shows up immediately in all text boxes.  This is as expected.  The problem is that now when you type into the `Name 2` text box, it value gets disconnected and the three box values are no longer in sync. [This is because of the way that JavaScript’s prototypal inheritance works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

To avoid, we should use `dot` in `ng-model`. For example, [have a look at this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fPPoTjXJ0P4bOx10RW34?p=preview)

```
      <form ng-submit='addName()'>

          Name 1: <input type='text' ng-model='contact.name'/>
          <input type='submit' value="Submit"/>
      </form>

      <p ng-switch='true'>
          Name 2: <input type='text' ng-switch-when="true"  ng-model='contact.name'/>
      </p>
      <p>
          Name 3: <input type='text' ng-model='contact.name'/>
      </p>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now the code works with all three text box always in sync.

**Source:**

1. [AngularJS MTV Meetup: Best Practices (2012/12/11)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY)
2. [5 AngularJS Antipatterns & Pitfalls](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/)
3. [Why ng-model value should contain a dot](http://learnwebtutorials.com/why-ng-model-value-should-contain-a-dot)
4. [Nested Scopes in AngularJS](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html)
5. [AngularJS: dot in ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)
6. [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)
7. [Does my ng-model really need to have a dot to avoid child $scope problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems)
8. [AngularJS: If you are not using a .(dot) in your models you are doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)