# angularjs scope variables are not working but works on second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have implemented print functionality. I am binding values to view using scope variables. When i click first time on print my values are not binding. When i click second time all my values will bind. Below is the print functionality.

```
 $scope.Print = function () {
                if ($scope.period == null) {
                    toastr.error($filter('translate')('Please select Year.'));
                }
                else {
                $scope.vehiclepriceprint = $cookieStore.get("carpriceprint");
                $scope.downpaymentprint = $cookieStore.get("downpayment");
      }
```

First time also i will be having values in cookie but not binding to view. Whenever i click second time on print button everything will be working
Below is the print button.

```
  <input type="button" value="{{'Print' | translate}}" class="blue-button"  ng-click="Print()" id="btnPrint">
```

Below is the html code of print.

```
   <span id="lblDownPayment">{{downpaymentprint}}</span>
   <span id="lblFinancialAmount">{{vehiclepriceprint}}</span>
```

May i know what is the issue i am facing here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please post the code where you're triggering your `print` function. i-e `ng-click` etc

Comment: Thank you. I have updated html.

Comment: Your `angular js` syntax is not valid.

Comment: May i know what would be the correct syntex?

Comment: If you are using this code in your web application then you are missing this -> `}`.

Comment: I have closed bracket. I have missed it here when copying code.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole do you fixed this issue?

Comment: No. I have not..

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$scope.$apply();` after updating the model values inside the controller. Now the view will get updated after that. This is a sample.

```
$scope.Print = function () {
      if ($scope.period == null) {
           toastr.error($filter('translate')('Please select Year.'));
      }
      else {
           $scope.vehiclepriceprint = $cookieStore.get("carpriceprint");
           $scope.downpaymentprint = $cookieStore.get("downpayment");
           $scope.$apply(); // To update view
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In controller or inside the print function i should apply?

Comment: You should apply it in inside the print function, to update the view. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$apply`. Although this is not a good approach.

```
$scope.Print = function () {
                    if ($scope.period == null) {
                        toastr.error($filter('translate')('Please select Year.'));
                    }
                    else {
                    $scope.vehiclepriceprint = $cookieStore.get("carpriceprint");
                    $scope.downpaymentprint = $cookieStore.get("downpayment");
                    $timeout(function(){//inject $timeout as dependency
                       $scope.$apply();
                    })
          }
```

Edit 1: Try this approach. here I have used Object (key:value) ways to update the print data.

```
$scope.printData = {};

$scope.Print = function () {
                    if ($scope.period == null) {
                        toastr.error($filter('translate')('Please select Year.'));
                    }
                    else {
                    $scope.printData.vehiclepriceprint = $cookieStore.get("carpriceprint");
                    $scope.printData.downpaymentprint = $cookieStore.get("downpayment");

          }
```

HTML:

```
<span id="lblDownPayment">{{printData.downpaymentprint}}</span>
   <span id="lblFinancialAmount">{{printData.vehiclepriceprint}}</span>
```

Comment: I have added but no luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still same problem. Whenever i click second time i will get required values

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole can you if are you getting value form $sookiestore on first click.

Comment: Hi Ved, I am getting on first click. I just displayed in console. also i debugged but binding to view is not happening

Comment: have you tried the my edited answer approach exactly same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155486/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-ved).

Answer (score 0):

### Analysis

Actually, `ngClick` calls `$scope.$apply()` [under-the-hood](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L3) (in the safest way possible). So you should not call it explicitly in your Controller.

Problem is that the variables you are trying to display/update are attached directly to the `$scope`, and this approach usually causes [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178943/does-my-ng-model-really-need-to-have-a-dot-to-avoid-child-scope-problems).

### Solution

```js
$scope.vm = {};

$scope.Print = function() {
    $scope.vm.vehiclepriceprint = $cookieStore.get("carpriceprint");
};
```

```html
<span id="lblFinancialAmount">{{ vm.vehiclepriceprint }}</span>
```