# angularjs - how to get in the controller the index of an item in a ng-repeat filter based on the value of one of its properties?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I use a ng-repeat in my html file to display filtered items:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | filter:query))">
  {{ item.name }}
</a>
```

In the controller, I'd like to get the index of an item based on one of his property.

Precision: I'd like to get the **index in the filtered list** and not in the whole list.

Here for example, it will be the index of the item witch name is `some_item_7`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.query = 'some';

    $scope.items = 
    [
      { name: 'some_item_1' },
      { name: 'another_item_2' },
      { name: 'some_item_3' },
      { name: 'another_item_4' },
      { name: 'some_item_5' },
      { name: 'another_item_6' },
      { name: 'some_item_7' },
      { name: 'another_item_8' },
      { name: 'some_item_9' }
    ];

    $scope.itemNext = function (item) {
      console.log(item.name);
    };

    $scope.getIndexFromName = function (name) {
      console.log("trying to get the index of the item with name = " + name);
    }

    $scope.getIndexFromName('some_item_7');

  }
]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/C8gL9qV1MyonTwDENO9L?p=preview

Any idea ?

Comment: update answer with code to initialize the filtered array, and a new plunker demo.  http://plnkr.co/NSvBz1yWvmeFgXITutZF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ng-repeat expression creates the filteredList array on your scope.
`<li ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | filter:query))">`

You can loop through it like any array, checking for the item matching the name parameter.
`$scope.filteredItems`

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/69nnbaZaulgX0odG7g7Y

See this related post: [AngularJS - how to get an ngRepeat filtered result reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721863/angularjs-how-to-get-an-ngrepeat-filtered-result-reference)

**Update**
Your comments indicate that you don't want to wait for ng-repeat to create the array of filtered items.  You can use the [$filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) service to easily initialize the same array before the page loads.  Use:

```
$scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, {name: $scope.query}, false)
```

Doing so does not interfere with `ng-repeat` saving its filter results to the same `filteredItems` array during DOM creation.

Here is an updated (and interactive) [demo](http://plnkr.co/NSvBz1yWvmeFgXITutZF): http://plnkr.co/NSvBz1yWvmeFgXITutZF

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but `$scope.filteredItems` is actually undefined in the `getIndexFromName()` function. Plunker updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/C8gL9qV1MyonTwDENO9L?p=preview

Comment: That is because of the timing of your call to the getIndexFromName function in the controller.  It occurs before the filter operation creates the filteredItems array.

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to init the app by calling the `getIndexFromName()` function ? Isn't there a way without forcing the user to click on the button ? Maybe a way to wait until the `filteredItems` array is done ?