# Is it possible to set a scope variable with the result of an angular filtered request?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I've got this code working nicely (see the code snipet as follows).

```
        <tr ng-repeat="diag in accidentsDiagnostics | filter:accidentsSearch(accidentSearchSelectedStage, accidentSearchSelectedOrgan, accidentSearchSelectedSymptom)">
            <td>{{diag[3]}}</td>
```

Is it possible to set a new model variable in the scope with the results (array), any time a new request is performed as the result of the user selection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save the filter results to your scope/model by adding an assignment to your repeat expression:

```
ng-repeat="diag in filtered = (accidentsDiagnostics | filter:accidentsSearch(...) )"
```

More info is available in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357197/angularjs-how-to-get-in-the-controller-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-ng-repeat-fil/22357706#22357706).

Comment: Could it be ng-model="dial in filtered = (accidentsDiagn etc.)" ? As I probably no longer use ng-repeat there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the filtering in your controller and save it there (don't forget to inject the $filter service into the controller).

```
$filter('accidentsSearch')(dataToFilter)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302334/725752