# Can't access array in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a solution that implements code from the following [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721863/angularjs-how-to-get-an-ngrepeat-filtered-result-reference) but I'm not able to access the variable. The code is...

```
<input ng-model="query">
 <div ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | orderBy:'order_prop' | filter:query | limitTo:4))">
   {{item}}
 </div>
<button ng-click='getFilteredItems()'>Collect</button>
```

Then in the controller I have the following:

```
$scope.getFilteredItems = function(){
   var items = $scope.filteredItems;
}
```

But in the Angular controller, I can't access the variable $scope.filteredItems, why is that?

Comment: Yes it is, I did that earlier in the controller

Comment: Seems to work. Can you create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/djbm6/