# In what scope is ng-repeat "as alias" available

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angular **1.4.8**. I want to save filtered result from ng-repeat and use it to determine whether to enable a "load more" button at the bottom of the list. I have looked at this question:

[AngularJS - how to get an ngRepeat filtered result reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721863/angularjs-how-to-get-an-ngrepeat-filtered-result-reference)

And many others, they suggest to use "as alias" from ng-repeat, here's what my code looks like:

```
  <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
    <li class="media">
      <div ng-repeat-start="item in items | limitTo: totalDisplayed as filteredResult">
        {{item}}
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat-end>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{filteredResult.length}}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click="loadMore()" ng-show="totalDisplayed <= filteredResult.length">
    more
  </button>
```

However, I found filteredResult.length is displayed fine right after ng-repeat, but the button is never shown. If I try to display filteredResult.length in where the button is, it will show null.

So is there a rule for "as alias" scope? I've seen plenty of examples work but mine doesn't, what am I missing here?

EDIT:

The accepted answer uses controllerAs which indeed will resolve the problem. However, charlietfl's comment using ng-init to save filteredResult to parent scope is also very neat and that's the solution I use in my code eventually.

Comment: Could you post a plunkr reproducing the problem? Is any of the `media-list tab-pane fade in active media` classes a selector for a directive that would have its own scope?

Comment: Works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/oSQP4KqezESBporw28vX?p=preview I suspect you have some other scope issue not shown in code above

Comment: Should work, do you try log totalDisplayed value?

Comment: @charlietfl: you are right, I think it has something to do with ng-if, in my actual code I have a ng-if="showSomething" in the ul(not the button) , but I don't understand why, see this example based on yours:http://plnkr.co/edit/qFUybIHFQrHVvIh76UFv?p=preview why the more button disappeared?

Comment: @swang because ng-if defines its own scope (it behaves as if you had `ng-controller="SomeOtherController"` on the ul). So filteredResult is set on the ngIf scope, and not on your controller scope. Since the button is out of the ng-if scope, it can't access filteredResult.

Comment: `ng-if` creates a child scope that's one reason `controllerAs` is popular but also setting models as objects on scope helps...insted of direct properties of scope for each variable

Comment: @charlietfl, can you please explain how to "setting models as objects on scope helps...insted of direct properties of scope for each variable", controllerAs is a good solution but it would require code change to every access of scope property, if there's a way to resolve this just when using ng-if i would prefer that.

Comment: what if you switch to `ng-show`? It doesn't create child scope.

Comment: @charlietfl that was my original solution, but I read about ng-if can improve the performance because DOM elements are not created at all. In my case i have 1000+ items, depends on the ng-if condition, only one half of them will be shown.

Comment: Here's a possibility using an object on scope and `ng-init` http://plnkr.co/edit/i0GKXAVTRjHWnelQpoAs?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some of classes in your `<ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">` or `<li class="media">` is selector for a directive that would have its own scope. So you store `filteredResult` in e.g. `tab-pane's scope` and then try to have access out of it's scope in outside of `ul` tag.

Try to use `Controller as` instead of scope:

```
angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    vm = this;
    // make an array from 1 to 10
    var arr = [];
    while (arr.length < 10) {
      arr.push(arr.length + 1)
    };

    vm.items = arr;
    vm.totalDisplayed = 5;
    vm.filteredResult = [];
  });
```

---

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  {{main.items}}
  <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
    <li class="media">
      <div ng-repeat-start="item in main.items | limitTo: main.totalDisplayed as filteredResult">
        {{item}}
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat-end>
      </div>
      <div>
        filteredResult = {{main.filteredResult = filteredResult}}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click="loadMore()" ng-show="main.totalDisplayed <= main.filteredResult.length">
    more
  </button>
</body>
```

---

http://plnkr.co/edit/drA1gQ1qj0U9VCN4IIPP?p=preview

Comment: what if i'm using ui-router and set Controller in the router rather than html? if i put ng-controller in <body> I would load my controller twice.

Comment: @swang You can use controller as in ui-router: `controllerAs: 'main'`