# Angularjs custom filter with expression alias and limitTo

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to show all items in an result set.  I have a custom search box which filters out results via a custom filter.  I now need to add pagination, but I also need all the items in the result set to be searchable, regardless of pagination. Here is the code:

`<div  ng-repeat= "items in obj | filter : {ownerId: controller.ownerId}  | customSearchFilter : controller.searchText as filteredResults | limitTo: controller.paginationLimit "></div>`

According to the ng-repeat documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat, It seems that the "as" micro-syntax can only be used at the end.  limitTo of course has to be after the filter in order for items to be searchable. Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 3):

The answer found in the link below allowed me to keep my alias and achieve the desired result.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11722324/1520950

Comment: If I `console.log filteredItems` I always get the data one filter later. It's not the result of the just changed filter, but the one from the previous change. Didn't you have this problem?